# How to check RabbitMQ is up and running when http port in disabled

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I need to check RabbitMQ is up and running before process starts.
We disabled the http port for some security purpose and we are using amqp to connect. Is there any way to do healthcheck ?

When http is enabled and if i use this url `15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F` to check it works fine, looking for alternate solution using `amqp`

Comment: Can you `ssh` onto the server or ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just connect to your rabbitmq instance and wrap this with a "try/catch" statement. If no exception is triggerd, your instance is a live otherwise is not.

You can look at the zend-diagnostic repo, or just use this library:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diagnostics/blob/master/src/Check/RabbitMQ.php